# Running test for maven project in Gitlab CI/CD

Tags: java, maven, gitlab

I have a project on gitlab and i would like to set up tests using gitlab CI/CD

My project structure is:

```
.
├── project
│   |── src
|   └── pom.xml
├── .gitlab-ci.yml
└── Licence.txt
```

My `.gitlab.ci.yml` script looks like:

```
image: maven:3.5.3

cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository/
    - target/

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn -f project/pom.xml compile


test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - mvn -f project/pom.xml test
```

My project has maven dependencies. But running this i recieve error:

```
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
Running after_script
Uploading artifacts for failed job
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

This looks like it wants to upload my maven artifact into remote repository or something.

What does it mean and how can ifixt this?

Thanks for help!

Comment: can you run this command on your local machine? mvn -f project/pom.xml test

Comment: You know `mvn test` also runs `mvn compile`, right? It is pointless to have 2 stages; you're currently compiling twice.

Comment: @tashkhisi if u run mvn test it works ( from intelij command line )

Comment: @Michael It does same thing i fi call just mvn test

Comment: add -X parameter to maven command din gitlab-ci to get debug level information: your command should be like this: mvn -f project/pom.xml -X test

Comment: @tashkhisi o got this error: [ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
 org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
 [FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for project:project:[unknown-version]: Could not find artifact <name> and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 24, column 13

Comment: First I recommend to change the directory structure and remove the `project` directory and move the `src` folder to root location as well as `pom.xml`. That will make the gitlab ci simply (just use `mvn test` ) no supplemental options etc. Furthermore the error output should be added completely...also don't try to separate things which belong together as Michael already mentioned.

Comment: what is in pom at line 24?

Comment: If it runs in your  machine without any problem, It should be internet connection problem!

Comment: @jejjejd I'm not saying it will fix it. I'm saying your understanding of Maven is fundamentally flawed if you think you need to do both.